# How to query all spatial trajectories that go from one region to another

Tags: mongodb, geometry, coordinates, pymongo, set-intersection

Consider a mongo db where each document corresponds to a spatial trajectory. That is, there is a field that contains an array for each document. Each array is a sequence of latitude/longitude pairs representing a geographical trajectory. Given two geographical regions R1, R2 defined by geojson polygones, find all trajectories that intersect first R1 and second R2. Given the size of the db, computational time is highly important.

My first attempt works but does not consider direction. Moreover, it is extremely slow. I use an aggregate framework (regions gjs[i]). My current pipeline contains the following.

`{"$match":{"location.lonlat":{'$geoIntersects':{'$geometry':gjs[0]}}}}, {"$match":{"location.lonlat":{'$geoIntersects':{'$geometry':gjs[1]}}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) :

$geoIntersects uses spherical geometry. $geoIntersects does not require a geospatial index. However, a geospatial index will improve query performance. Only the 2dsphere geospatial index supports $geoIntersects.

So you have a problem:  your query works because `$geoIntersects` does *not* require an index but it is slow because there is no index.  To speed it up, you must create a `2dsphere` index because that is the only index (i.e. NOT a `2d` index) used by `$geoIntersects` -- which unfortunately will **not work** on legacy arrays of coordinate points (your "trajectories").

My recommendation is to go full GeoJSON:

1. Convert your `location.lonlat` array of points to GeoJSON `LineString` object, e.g.

```
{location: {
        "trajectory" : {
            "type" : "LineString",
            "coordinates" : [ [10,60] , [10,61] , [10,62] ]
        }
    },
```

You could do this with a *non-destructive* update to create a new field `trajectory` as a peer to `lonlat` in the `location` object.  Note the use of the array form of `update()` that permits pipelines and thus the `$location.lonlat` array can be copied into the new field:

```
db.foo.update({}, [ {$set: {"location.trajectory": {type: "LineString", coordinates: "$location.lonlat"}}} ], {multi:true});
```

2. Create a `2dsphere` index on `location.trajectory`:

```
db.foo.createIndex({"location.trajectory":"2dsphere"});
```

Your queries will now be performant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the line direction ? Unfortunately, I dont have rights to modify the collection so I cannot add the index ...

Comment: That is something you will have to compute in code with the material returned from the query and subject your rules.    Too many nuances about "direction" vs. "bearing" and how to find the proper "pin-point" for a polygon that intersects a line (your trajectory).   If you are interested in ideas of how to compute such a thing, take a look at https://github.com/buzzm/hurricane.   A quicky idea?  Assuming one region does not subsume the other AND trajectory is monotonically increasing in longitude (X), then compare the leftmost point of R1 to R2 to get direction.